# Deploys an node js app on Microsoft Azure without Github

Tags: node.js, azure

I discovered Microsoft Azure few days ago and I'm a little confused by all those services and documentations.

I don't really know what I am supposed to use, why etc.

I actually want to deploy a simple node application with a MySQL database without using the Github deploy integration.

Am I supposed to use Azure **Web App** service or should I **create a virtual machine** and connect to it with SSH ?

I already try to do something with the Web App service. I pushed my files on the Web App FTP but I couldn't figured out how to launch (from command lines) and access the application.

The documentation mainly concern the Github way so it's a little confusing.

Thanks a lot for your answers and advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you deploy your node.js app to Azure Web Apps, Azure will use IIS to host your app. It means that you do not need to launch the app manually, it looks like the PHP scripts host in Apache.

There are some additional thing to do to create the node.js app in Azure Web Apps.

1) You'll need to put your app to root folder of the Azure website (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`).

2) Generate `web.config` for the app, the file can be found at [this post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps).

3) Set a port value like `process.env.PORT || 3000` instead of `3000`.

Now you can access your app with this endpoint: `http://<youwebsitename>.azurewebsites.net`.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it asap and come back to you. I was wondering, what if I want to check log poped out to the common nodejs console ?

Comment: To get stdout and stderr logs, you'll need to create `iisnode.yml` file. Then you are able to read it via Kudu Console. Please follow the steps at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started#get-stdout-and-stderr-logs-from-iisnode]).

Comment: If my post was helpful, please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Done! I did not have the time to test it but I'll and, by the way, your post is totaly usefull !